# strange behaviour with child route in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs3

I have a problem with vue3 router when I use child route. the child route is displayed in a component on the homepage, this InfoLayer.vue component is only sometimes visible, depending on a flag in the store.

roughly the router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import IntroView from '../gameviews/IntroView.vue'
import PuzzleView from '../gameviews/PuzzleView.vue'

var routes = [

   {
     path: "/homepage",
     name: "homepage",
     component: HomeView,
     children: [
                 {
                   path: '/homepage/intro',
                   name: "intro",
                   component: IntroView
                 },
                 {
                   path: '/homepage/puzzle',
                   name: "puzzle",
                   component: PuzzleView
                 }
 
     ]
   }, ...
```

There are of course more routes in the project, and they all work wonderfully. Only the child routes don't work, the homepage view is always displayed instead of the intro or puzzle. No error message, even the incorrectly displayed view works.

the part in the layer.vue component looks like this:

```
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
                 <transition name="slidefade" appear mode="out-in" >
                     <component :is="Component" class="animated" :key="route.path" />
                 </transition>
               </router-view>
```

Even an extra push when loading the IntroLayer component always loads the homepage

```
 onMounted(() => {

       setTimeout(() => {
         router.push( {path:"/homepage/puzzle"} );
       }, 2000);
```

why isn't the child shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child routes are currently set to be matched when the paths are `/homepage/homepage/intro` and `/homepage/homepage/puzzle` respectively (or they would be, as they're not supposed to be prepended with `/` either). Check the Vue Router documentation on [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes)

Think of a child route path as being an *extension* of the parent path.

You want to define your routes like so:

```js
{
  path: '/homepage',
  name: 'homepage',
  component: HomeView,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'intro',
      name: 'intro',
      component: IntroView
    },
    {
      path: 'puzzle',
      name: 'puzzle',
      component: PuzzleView
    }
  ]
}
```

So the child routes will now match when the path is `/homepage/intro` or `/homepage/puzzle` respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, the / is always loaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "/ is always loaded".  How so?  Also, probably should've asked earlier but does `HomeView` component have a `<router-view />` in its template?  That is the only way to display nested route components.  You may want to show this code in your question.

Comment: "/" means the default path.   And Thanks, that was the mistake, the router view wasn't even in the right view.